# How do you enable the DNS extension to ml2 in OpenStack?

Tags: networking, dns, openstack

In [one doc it says](https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/charm-specs/specs/pike/implemented/internal-dns.html),

> **To enable the internal DNS resolution**, the neutron-server service must be configured with the dns_domain config option set to a value other than openstacklocal in neutron.conf file **and the dns extension driver must be enabled in the `ml2_conf.ini` file. In order to enable internal DNS resolution, the user must set the `enable-ml2-dns` to `True`.** The default value is `False` in order to provide backwards compatibility with existing deployments.

In [another doc it says this](https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/networking-guide/config-dns-int.html)

> Add dns to extension_drivers in the `[ml2]` section of `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini`. The following is an example:
>
> ```
> [ml2]
> extension_drivers = port_security,dns
> ```

Which method is the correct method for enabling the ml2 dns extension? Are we setting the `enable-ml2-dns` to true, or adding a `dns` driver in the  `extension_drivers` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link [charm](https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/charm-specs/specs/pike/implemented/internal-dns.html) - is for an Openstack deployed with Charm.

The second doc is correct. The file at `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini` should be changed on the controllers. But the exact location will depend on how Openstack was deployed.