# What does "extension list" show in the OpenStack cli?

Tags: openstack

Are these extensions shown with OpenStack's client `openstack extension list` extensions that are *available* or extensions that are *enabled*? I ask, because there is a notion of an extension that is not enabled. And I'm wondering if this is showing that the extension exists and is enabled, or that it *can* be enabled by an administrator?

Also somethings mention [`ml2` extension drivers](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/15507/18965), are these drivers listed in the output of `extension list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `extension` command will list the plugins that are enabled

```
openstack extension list | grep dns
```

```
| FloatingIpDns                                                                                                                                                  | os-floating-ip-dns                    | Floating IP DNS support.                                                                                                                                 |
| DNS Integration                                                                                                                                                | dns-integration                       | Provides integration with DNS.                                                                                                                           |
```