# How can I get more information about an OpenStack extension?

Tags: openstack

[There is *something* (still not exactly sure because of the documentation) that allows DNS internal resolution in OpenStack through an extension](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/15507/18965). I'm wondering if any of these do that deed (from the output of `extension list`)

- `os-floating-ip-dns` - Floating IP DNS support.
- `dns-integration` - Provides integration with DNS.
- `dns-domain-ports` - Allows the DNS domain to be specified for a network port.

These are all very interesting to me. Is there anyway to find more information about what these do than the 4 or 5 vague words their described with with `extension list`?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see

- os-floating-ip-dns - Floating IP DNS support. This seems to be limited to integrating floating IP DNS with external DNS services. Not a DNS inside Openstack.
- dns or dns_domain_ports : Allows you to add a FQDN to a port in Openstack. Then, if it's an internal network, the dnsmasq instance (that acts as DHCP and DNS) will be able to resolve the zone and the associated hostname.

`dns_domain_ports` seems to be the new plugin name for Queens and up. [Change in config](https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/charm-neutron-api/+/635667/2/hooks/neutron_api_context.py)

There doesn't seem to be any configuration for `dns-integration`. It's either `dns` or `dns_domain_ports`

Comment: While this is great information, where did you find it? Teach a man to fish, etc.

Comment: No great magic there - like I mentioned in the post : https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/charm-neutron-api/+/635667/2/hooks/neutron_api_context.py

And some trial and error in my own Openstack lab. Unfortunately, the Openstack doc is pretty barebones for some uses cases.